# Custom mouse events on links

Tags: javascript, html, hover

[Please see this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uguAA/1/)

If you hover your mouse exactly on the link, a different link appears. But different text is also appearing when you hover on left or right of the link. I want to make the hover effect only when it is being hovered on the exact link.

How can I do this?

My `HTML` code:

```
<ul id="nav">
    <li id="a1"><a href="#">original link 1</a></li>
    <li id="a2" class="hack"><a href="#">hover link 1</a></li>
    <li id="b1"><a href="#">original link 2</a></li>
    <li id="b2" class="hack"><a href="#">hover link 2</a></li>
    <li id="c1"><a href="#">original link 3</a></li>
    <li id="c2" class="hack"><a href="#">hover link 3</a></li>
</ul>
```

My `Javascript` code:

```
$('.hack').hide();
$("#nav li").mouseenter(function() {
    $('#' +this.id.charAt(0)+"2").show();
    $('#' +this.id.charAt(0)+"1").hide();
  }).mouseleave(function() {
    $('#' +this.id.charAt(0)+"1").show();
    $('#' +this.id.charAt(0)+"2").hide();
  });
```

Please see the fiddle to see the effect I'm referring to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following:

```
$('.hack').hide();
$("#nav li a").mouseenter(function() {
    $('#' +this.parentNode.id.charAt(0)+"2").show();
    $('#' +this.parentNode.id.charAt(0)+"1").hide();
  }).mouseleave(function() {
    $('#' +this.parentNode.id.charAt(0)+"1").show();
    $('#' +this.parentNode.id.charAt(0)+"2").hide();
});
```

You want to initiate the `hover` events on the `a` tags rather than the `li`s themselves.

[**EXAMPLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/uguAA/6/)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using mouseenter event shortcut it would be better if you use event delegation and add event on `"a"` element like this...

```
$("#nav li").on({
    "mouseenter" : function() { },
    "mouseleave" : function() { }
}, "a");
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess i updated the fiddle. I just added this style:

```
#nav li {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your js, bind your function to `"#nav li a"` instead.